# Why can I not see this subnav in IE8 /IE9 ? Switching to display block doesn't show it

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, css-tables

I really hate asking a question this direct but I've been trying to figure out why the subnav on the left (hover over "About Us" ) won't show up in IE for a few hours and I can't recreate the problem in a fiddle :-/
Here's the site: 
 http://quinnhr.adsinchosting5.com/

***update*** Definitely look at the code on that ^ site, because this is just a snippet of where I think the problem is for the sake of brevity. ***/update*** 
Here's the a snippet of the html, and css:

```
        <nav> <!-- left sidebar -->
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> Capabilities </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> Pricing </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    <ul id="subNizzle"> <!-- this UL is the issue, see css -->
                        <li class="subNav">
                            <a href="#">someone's name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="subNav">
                            <a href="#">some else's name</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="subNav">
                            <a href="#">another name</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

CSS ***yes i know display none is set, the jquery code overwrites it on hover, see quinnhr.adsinchosting5.com for code.  Turning off

```
section aside: first-of-type ul li a{
display:table-cell;
}
```

at least makes the subnav show up, but it shows up on top of the existing nav and moving it to the right with by:

```
section aside:first-of-type ul li a{
 position: absolute;
 }
 section aside:first-of-type ul li ul{
 position: absolute;
 right:-100px;
 z-index: 1000;
 }
```

moves it to the right enough for it to show up and illustrate that it's being hidden outside of the nav...

```
  section aside:first-of-type ul {
  display: table;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute; }

section aside:first-of-type ul li {
  display: table;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px; }

section aside:first-of-type ul li a {
  color: #F0EBDA;
  display: table-cell; 
  height: 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  position:absolute;  /* update */
}


section aside:first-of-type ul li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: -45px 0px 0px 179px;
  padding: 0px;
  position:absolute; /* update */
  right: -100px;    /* update */
}
```

jQuery:
    Query(document).ready(function($) {

```
$('li a').addClass("nahbro");
$('ul li ul').css({"margin-left": "-10px", "padding" : "0px", "margin-top" : "-45px"});
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).switchClass("nahbro", "prepare", 400);
    $('#subNizzle', this).fadeIn().switchClass("nahbro", "prepare", 300);
    $('.subNav').hover(function(){
        $(this).switchClass("prepare", "liSelected", 200);
    },function(){
        $(this).switchClass("liSelected", "prepare", 200);
    });

}, function(){
    $(this).switchClass("prepare", "nahbro", 400);
    $('#subNizzle', this).fadeOut().switchClass("liSelected", "nahbro", 500);

});
```

I think it has something to do with a display:table / display: table-cell / display: block somewhere in the chain...

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `<nav>` and `section` tag and IE9 doesn't support That. you need to replace the `nav, section` tags with `div`

Comment: If you look at the actual source on  http://quinnhr.adsinchosting5.com/ you will see that I am using modernizr/htmlshiv ... I should've said that. definitely look at the code on the site

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer why the subnav wasn't showing:
it was positioned correctly but when:

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d9090', endColorstr='#545e5f',GradientType=0 );

is applied, for some reason it hides everything outside of the scope of the filter.
which is wack.
but at least now i know.